# Create Windows 10 ControlTemplate in code-behind file

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have a CheckBox, which I have defined in my xaml file with the help of a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate. I have done this because I needed to overwrite the existing CheckBox image. Here is my CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="CheckBox_Checked">
    <CheckBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Image Source="Assets/unchecked_checkbox.png"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </CheckBox.Template>
</CheckBox>
```

So, that works. But now when I want to change the image when the user checks the CheckBox, I assume I have to do it in code-behind. I tried to create a template but...

```
ControlTemplate ctr = new ControlTemplate();
ctr.TargetType = typeof(CheckBox);
ctr.
```

as you can see I'm stuck. The only thing that pops up here is SetValue, but this needs a parameter of type DependencyProperty as well as an object.

I need help...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you don't need to use Template in this case. CheckBox is ContentControl. You can set content directly.
For example:

```
youCheckBox.Content = new Image()
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage()
            {
                UriSource = new Uri("Assets/unchecked_checkbox.png")
            }
        };
```

Secondly Imho better way to change content when CheckBox is checked is do it in XAML. For example you can edit CheckBox (its copy of default style of CheckBox thats why its so long :)) style:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle"
           TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="8,5,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CombinedStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedNormal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UncheckedDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedNormal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBoxImage"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                            HERE YOU SHOULD SET IMAGE FOR CHECKED
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Assets/unchecked_checkbox.png" /> 
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateNormal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="Transparent" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Glyph"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="&#xE73C;" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Height="32"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle"
                                       Fill="Transparent"
                                       Height="20"
                                       Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                                       StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}"
                                       UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                       Width="20" />
                            <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}"
                                      FontSize="20"
                                      FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                      Glyph="&#xE001;"
                                      Opacity="0" />
                        </Grid>
                        <!--YOUR IMAGE-->
                        <Image x:Name="CheckBoxImage"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Source="Assets/unchecked_checkbox.png" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

There are VisualStates for checked state. You can style it as you wish :)

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising! First thing tomorrow when I get to the office Ima try it!